# how to use ggplot to visualise grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have the following code which generate the following results:

```
years <- seq(1930, 2020, by = 10)
length(years)
years
labels <- paste(1 + years[-length(years)], years[-1], sep = "-")
length(labels)
labels
SP500 %>% mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10), labels = labels)) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% summarise(return = mean(`Annual\n% Change`))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   decade    return
   <fct>      <dbl>
 1 1931-1940  0.014
 2 1941-1950  0.077
 3 1951-1960  0.124
 4 1961-1970  0.056
 5 1971-1980  0.058
 6 1981-1990  0.098
 7 1991-2000  0.157
 8 2001-2010  0.018
 9 2011-2020  0.121
10 NA         0.04
```

and my question is how can I put this result into a bar or line chart?
I have been trying to do that for the last few hours  but I keep getting errors, although I feel the answer is simple it seems like I just can't see it

```
years <- seq(1930, 2020, by = 10)
length(years)
labels <- paste(1 + years[-length(years)], years[-1], sep = "-")
length(labels)
SP500 %>% mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10), labels = labels)) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% summarise(return = mean(`Annual\n% Change`)) %>%
  ggplot(SP500, aes(x = decade, y = return)) +
  geom_col()
```

Error in `ggplot()`:
! Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.

```
SP500 %>% ggplot(
  ss <- SP500 %>% mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10))) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% summarise(return = mean(`Annual\n% Change`)), aes_(x=ss[,1], y= ss[,2]))  + geom_line()
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: In your first `ggplot` code, you are piping the data into `ggplot`, therefore you should leave the first argument in `ggplot` empty (i.e. the `data` argument). Try `SP500 %>% mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10), labels = labels)) %>% group_by(decade) %>% summarise(return = mean(\`Annual\n% Change\`)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = decade, y = return)) + geom_col()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are piping the result of your data manipulation through to ggplot, but also passing the name of the data frame as the first argument to ggplot.

Remember that doing

```r
data_frame %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))
```

Is the same as doing

```
ggplot(data = data_frame, mapping = aes(x, y))
```

But doing

```r
data_frame %>% ggplot(data_frame, aes(x, y))
```

Is the same as doing

```r
ggplot(data = data_frame, mapping = data_frame, aes(x, y))
```

And of course, you get an error because you can't pass a data frame to the `mapping` argument.

So you can do

```r
SP500 %>% 
  mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10), labels = labels)) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% 
  summarise(return = mean(`Annual\n% Change`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = decade, y = return)) +
  geom_col()
```

**or**

```r
SP500 <- SP500 %>% 
  mutate(decade = cut(SP500$Year,seq(1930,2020,by=10), labels = labels)) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% 
  summarise(return = mean(`Annual\n% Change`))

ggplot(SP500, aes(x = decade, y = return)) +
  geom_col()
```

Both of which result in:

[image]

The above plot was made with the following code which includes the data taken from your question. If you copy and paste this code block into your R console, it will produce the same plot:

```r
SP500 <- structure(list(decade = structure(1:9, .Label = c("1931-1940", 
"1941-1950", "1951-1960", "1961-1970", "1971-1980", "1981-1990", 
"1991-2000", "2001-2010", "2011-2020"), class = "factor"), return = c(0.014, 
0.077, 0.124, 0.056, 0.058, 0.098, 0.157, 0.018, 0.121)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(SP500, aes(decade, return)) + geom_col()
```